# Cambiar color item seleccionado en CheckBoxList, C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms, color

**¿Es posible cambiar el color de fondo del item seleccionado en un CheckBoxList?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Algo como esto:

```
foreach (var item_select in checkBoxList1.CheckedItems)
{
   checkBoxList1.Items[item_select].BackColor = Color.SeaGreen;
}
```

> Pero esto: `checkBoxList1.Items[item_select].BackColor = Color.SeaGreen;` **no existe**. Y si lo hago asi: `checkBoxList1.BackColor = Color.SeaGreen;` entonces sombreará el `CheckBoxList` completo.

¿Alguna idea?

Entorno: Visual Studio 2010 & .NET Netframework 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En windows forms no es no es solo asignarle la propiedad para un cambio de color que buscas, hay que re definir la clase del checkbox para ejecutar el drawn, quien es el que permitirá el cambio de color.

[Del sitió en ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17588913/4068497)

Comment: He visto ejemplos parecidos, pero esto: `Attributes.Add("style", "color: SeaGreen");`. El Visual Studio **No me lo reconoce.**, Hace falta algún Using o referencia?

Comment: Ya miré con atención, había escrito para otro lenguaje. Edité mi respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto!. Ya que es de ese modo, entonces crearé un control de usuario así lo puedo reutilizar cuantas veces quiera en otras ocaciones.